# Sudden drop in search engine position

Tags: google-ranking, disavow-links

how should I handle a sudden surge in backlinks for a specific keyword and a rapid response from Google resulting in a drop in rankings for that keyword and others as well? Is it necessary to disavow links in this situation? Will the keyword's position be built up from beyond position 100? What else should I be aware of?
I'm trying to be clear, but I'm just a self-taught SEO enthusiast.